# How to expose Openshift enviroment variables on a json

Tags: json, openshift

I have installed node-push-server. The configuration is loaded from a json like this:

```
{
    "webPort": 8000,

    "mongodbUrl": "mongodb://username:password@localhost/database",

    "gcm": {
        "apiKey": "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"
    },

    "apn": {
        "connection": {
            "gateway": "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",
            "cert": "/path/to/cert.pem",
            "key": "/path/to/key.pem"
        },
        "feedback": {
            "address": "feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com",
            "cert": "/path/to/cert.pem",
            "key": "/path/to/key.pem",
            "interval": 43200,
            "batchFeedback": true
        }
    }
}
```

How can I set the enviroment variables for my application in this json file?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. You should be able to change all these settings in the code though. For example in node you can do: `process.env.OPENSHIFT_VARIABLENAME` to read an environment variable.

Example for MongoDB connection string from [docs](https://blog.openshift.com/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps/):

```
//provide a sensible default for local development
mongodb_connection_string = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/' + db_name;

//take advantage of openshift env vars when available:
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL){
    mongodb_connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + db_name;
}
```

As an alternative, there is a quick and easy deployable gear called AeroGear Push that might serve your needs.

Comment: Yes, I read the docs but I dont have idea about AeroGearPush. I go to read this. Many thanks and sorry for my English :D

Answer (score 1):

Config files can be awkward because including them in your source repo isn't always a good move.

OpenShift deployments are mostly `git push`-driven, so there are several options for helping you correctly resolve your configs on the server.

Configuring your service using ENV vars is the most common approach, but since this one requires a flat file, you'll need to find a way to update the file with the correct values.

If you know what keys and values are needed, you should be able to write a script that updates the example json, or merges two json objects to produce a flat config file including the strings `node-pushserver` will expect.

It looks like `mongodbUrl`, `webPort`, (and `domain`?) would need to be populated with OpenShift-provided values (when available).  `config-multipaas` might be able to help with that.

I would probably [implement the config bootstrapping / merging work as a build step](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-action-hooks.html), allowing you to prep the config file and start `node-pushserver` in it's usual way